# Ask for notification in ViewController.

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Currently, my app asks users for notification permission right on initial opening, how do I ask them when they click a specific button and how do I run the registerForRemoteNotifications in that ViewController when they click yes. The following is my AppDelegate where its currently promoting users.

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    FirebaseApp.configure()

    UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate

        let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
    } else {
        let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
            UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    }

    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}
```

Comment: Moving that code to any UIViewController will do the same thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this inside a ViewController and run the function inside an action or the ViewDidLoad.

```
func registerForRemoteNotification() {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
            if error == nil{
                UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        }

    }
    else {
        UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set it in your `completionHandler`.

This line: `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })`

Should be:

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: authOptions,
        completionHandler: { granted, error in 
    if granted {
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        // Do other things after user has been granted authorization
    }
})
```